# jQuery plugin and storing state of page elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a plugin that makes a textbox behave like numeric Excel cell with thousand separators.

Following line makes the textbox value thousand-separated...

```
$('#xlLike').excelify();
```

...and internally marks the targeted input tag to save the 'excelified' state (like: *this input is excelified*).

Following line finds all such 'excelified' inputs and removes separators from their values...

```
$('[data-excelify]').excelify({toNumber: true});
```

This internal marking is done using .attr() that fiddles with DOM. However, I could have used .data() and have jQuery do the marking in memory. After all, I could have used some class name inside the plugin to mark those textboxes.

Maybe it's not a big deal but I would like to know which approach to store states is *the right one* when writing a plugin.

P.S. Here's the plugin example if needed: http://jsfiddle.net/ozrentk/W8fq9/26/

Comment: Unambiguously, use `.data()`.

Comment: @beetroot-beetroot: could you explain why?

Comment: Performance. jQuery's `.data()` is implemented wholly in javascript. `.attr()` and classes are implemented in the DOM, therefore slower to write/read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- REWRITTEN ANSWER --

My opinion:

One of the advantages when using jquery `data()` is that you can **store your data in a very structured manner**. Although `data()` can be manipulated from outside you can use the plugin in a *class-like* way, where you have your values stored *lets say* inside the object.

On the other hand using `[data-]` attributes opens up interesting possibilities when you want to manipulate the data from outside using the DOM, e.g. when inserting elements with a *prepared* attribute value or want other scripts to change values etc..

That said, **using the `[data-]` attribute as storage does not necessarily require having an interface like yours where you have to use the attribute value as selector to change states for those elements**. This is a crucial difference in how you apply a plugin. As you parse the DOM again to find out which elements have a specific state, it may have a huge impact on performance - e.g. when imagining a spreadsheet like web application with large amounts of affected cells.

The following is an **example** for a plugin interface which can perform those tasks much better in my eyes. Further more it demonstrates the usage of data as internal storage:

```
(function($){
    var defaults = {
        //...
    };
    var methods = {
        init : function(options){
            var properties = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);
            return this.each(function(){
                var $element = $(this);
                var data = $element.data('foo');
                //...
                if (!data) {
                    $(this).data('foo', {
                        'properties' : properties
                        //...
                    });
                    //...
                    methods._bind.apply(this, []);
                }
            });
        },
        '_bind' : function(){
            var $element = $(this);
            $element.data('foo', $.extend(true, {}, $element.data('foo'), {
                //...
            }));
            //...
        },
        '_unbind' : function(){
            var $element = $(this);
            $element.data('foo', $.extend(true, {}, $element.data('foo'), {
                //...
            }));
            //...
        },
        'add' : function(){
            return this.each(function(){
                //...
                methods._bind.apply(this, []);
            });
        },
        'remove' : function(){
            return this.each(function(){
                //...
                methods._unbind.apply(this, []);
            });
        }
    };
    $.fn.foo = function(arg){
        if (arg) {
            if (typeof arg === 'string') {
                if (arg.indexOf('_') === 0) {
                    arg = '';
                }
                if (methods[arg]) {
                    return methods[arg].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
                }
            }
        }
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

So you can then use it like this:

```
$xl = $('.xl');
$xl.excelify('add');
$xl.excelify('remove');
```

Or even a toggle (not implemented in the above code example):

```
$xlLike.excelify();
```

Comment: Could you explain where is the advantage of data() over attr()? I cant see that from your code. Btw, you can see my plugin implementation in the fiddle I've linked.

Comment: Regarding your question and the more or less comprehensible downvote to my original answer I have rewritten it to make clear what before existed only in my thoughts but was not written down here... ;)

Comment: Could those downvoting my answer please explain why?

Comment: I'm not acquainted with this kind of more advanced jQuery plugin structure but I see the point. Next thing I have to do is run a side by side comparison of .data() vs .attr() performance test - read, write, lookup etc.